# Class 'Dropbox\AppInfo' not found - PHP

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, dropbox-sdk

My code, script start.php in app folder:

```
require __DIR__ . '../../dropbox-php-sdk-master/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

$dropboxKey    = '';
$dropboxSecret = '';
$appName       = '';

$appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret);
```

My folder structure:

```
1.app
  1.1. start.php
2.dropbox-php-sdk-master
  2.1.vendor 
    2.1.1. autoload.php
3.index.php (calls function start.php)
```

And when I call the index.php i recive this erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dropbox\AppInfo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\dropboxapi\app\start.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\dropboxapi\index.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\dropboxapi\app\start.php on line 12
```

I follow some tutorials on the internet and they all have the same structure, what Im doing bad?

Comment: Apparently there's a custom autoload.php that you should require instead, within the Dropbox source folder itself. But it also appears you're using an [obsolete version of the dropbox SDK](https://packagist.org/packages/dropbox/dropbox-sdk) (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: yes im using that version, why?

Comment: Well, it's obsolete as it queries the old v1 API, and you shouldn't use it anymore, from what I understood. You should use either of the ones listed on the [official docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks).